# Does lua have something like python's slice

Tags: lua

Like in python I can use slice. Like following

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
a=b[0:3]
```

Can I do that kind of operation in Lua without a loop. Or Loop is the most efficient way to do that

Comment: https://github.com/justincormack/slice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no syntax sugar for doing this, so your best bet would be doing it via a function:

```
function table.slice(tbl, first, last, step)
  local sliced = {}

  for i = first or 1, last or #tbl, step or 1 do
    sliced[#sliced+1] = tbl[i]
  end

  return sliced
end

local a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
local b = table.slice(a, 2, 3)
print(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4])
print(b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4])
```

Keep in mind that I haven't tested this function, but it's more or less what it should look like without checking input.

Edit: [I ran it at ideone](http://ideone.com/b0d61z).

Comment: There **is** syntax sugar for this, see the answer from @Fantix King

Answer (score 41):

By creating a new table using the result of [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack) ([`unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) before Lua 5.2):

```
for key, value in pairs({table.unpack({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 4)}) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

This generates...

```
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

(Tested in Lua 5.3.4 and Lua 5.1.5.)

Answer (score 3):

xlua package has table.splice function. (luarocks install xlua)

```
yourTable = {1,2,3,4}
startIndex = 1; length = 3
removed_items, remainder_items = table.splice(yourTable, startIndex, length)
print(removed_items) -- 4
print(remainder_items) -- 1,2,3
```

see: https://github.com/torch/xlua/blob/master/init.lua#L640