# How can I shift all of the tables down after removing a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

In this code:

```
t = {
    num = '',
}

t[0].num = '0'
t[1].num = '1'
t[2].num = '2'
```

Is there a way for me to delete `t[0]`, then shift all of the table's values down, so that afterword it looks like this:

```
t[0].num = '1'
t[1].num = '2'
```

Example with imaginary functions:

```
t = {
    num = '',
}

t[0].num = '0'
t[1].num = '1'
t[2].num = '2'

for i=0,tableLength(t) do
    print(t[i])
end
--Output: 012

remove(t[0])

for i=0,tableLength(t) do
    print(t[i])
end
--Output: 12
```

Comment: Your code does not run because t[0] is nil.

Comment: Are you sure you need the indexes to start at 0? Lua's semantics and standard library assume that arrays start at index 1. If you can make your array 1-based, you can just use `table.remove(t, 1)`

Comment: My response to your last question https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.remove should have made you refer to the Lua reference manual. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.remove   you don't learn Lua by getting snippets from other people. if you'd learn the very basics you could come up with a solution or at least half a solution yourself. so please read the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t = {
    num = '',
}

t[0].num = '0'
t[1].num = '1'
t[2].num = '2'
```

This code will cause errors for indexing `t[0]`, a nil value.

`t` only has one field and that is `t.num`

You need to do something like this:

```
t = {}
for i = 0, 2 do
  t[i] = {num = tostring(i)}
end
```

if you want to create the desired demo table.

As there are many useful functions in Lua that assume 1-based indexing you I'd recommend starting at index 1.

```
local t = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Option 1:

```
table.remove(t, 1)
```

Option 2:

```
t = {table.unpack(t, 2, #t)}
```

Option 3:

```
t = table.move(t, 2, #t, 1, t)
t[#t] = nil
```

Option 4:

```
for i = 1, #t-1 do
  t[i] = t[i+1]
end
t[#t] = nil
```

There are more options. I won't list them all. Some do it in place, some result in new table objects.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48161186/8124983), by creating a new table using the result of [table.unpack](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack):

```lua
t = {table.unpack(t, 1, #t)}
```